# How to store JWT token in session?

Tags: node.js, session

I'm learning to use jsonwebtoken (jwt) and express-session in NodeJS to store token from jwt but I can't wrap my head around it.

```
.then((result)=>{
    var token = jwt.sign({usertype: 'parent', id: result.id}, 'secret', {expiresIn: '1h'});
    // response with token
    res.json({token: token});
});
```

as you can see above I can respond with the token to the client side, but how do I store the token?

I read both those documentation but still don't get it. It looks like if I want to use session in my request, I can read it on the server side with `req.session` but how to store on the client's side isn't clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @mabc224's comment above, the solution is to store it in localstorage.

Comment: Using local storage exposes your token to a xss attack.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry i have not enough reputation to comment your post. Why do you want to store it in client side ? You can do that using cookies, but I think that it is not a good idea. Your token expires within one hour, you can just let it in the session

Comment: I know that doesn't seem like a good idea, but after logging in or creating a new account, I send a token to the user, then the user will send several more requests (like edit profile, pull info from some APIs, change password... or even delete account). How would you verify user's information for those requests?

Comment: I think that the best solution is to let express to makes requests to your api, so you can use the token for your requests on the server side. If you want the user edit his profile, on the express route user/SOMEID/edit for example, you have to post parameters (name, surname, ...) from the client, take this parameters from server side (express) and send them to your api using the token stored in the session

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. the problem i have is the token isn't stored in the session. i've looked in headers and others suggested places i could find online but it's nowhere to be found.

Comment: if you want to store something in the session, you have to do req.session.token = token, and everytime you want to retrive it: const myToken = req.session.token || null

Comment: @Viet you don't need to store token at server. Just store it on client side in localstorage. When you need to make secure request like edit profile, just send this token to server in header of api request. and validate it before processing request in middleware. Upon validation, process request and response back. If you need to use decoded information from token, then keep that decoded info in request variable, like req.decoded = jwtDecodedToken;
Example:
https://scotch.io/tutorials/authenticate-a-node-js-api-with-json-web-tokens#toc-route-middleware-to-protect-api-routes

Comment: Yes this is an easier solution, but I think that local storage has a xss vulnerability isn't it? I think that store it on the session or on a http only cookie and implement a csrf token for requests from client to server is a more secured solution. But maybe I'm wrong

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. The best solution is to store it in local storage, or in cookie and use directly from the client side.

Comment: Thank you Ciro and mabc224 I have been able to do that based on your suggestions with localstorage. Could you please paste your answer here so I could mark it as the correct answer?